# Laravel 4 many to many and polymorphic in one direction

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphism

I'd like a relationship between a few models that is a many to many and polymorphic in one direction, this is how I've solved it for now but it really bothers me to have it this way, I loose all attach(), detach() etc functionality and it should be a simple way to do this. Can't find any docs, examples or anything, all I've seen are just so basic.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class Category extends Eloquent {
  /*
  public function categorizables() {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
  */
  public function categorizables(){
    $categorizables = new Collection();
    $categorizableRows = DB::table('categorizables')->where('category_id', $this->id)->get();
    foreach ($categorizableRows as $categorizable) {
      $class = $categorizable->categorizable_type;
      $categorizables->add($class::find($categorizable->categorizable_id));
    }
    return $categorizables;
  }
}

class Article extends Eloquent {
  /*
  public function categories() {
    return $this->morphMany('Category','categorizable');
  }
  */
  public function categories(){
    $categoryRows = DB::table('categorizables')
      ->where('categorizable_id', $this->id)
      ->where('categorizable_type', get_class($this))->get();
    $categoryIds = array();
    foreach ($categoryRows as $category) {
      $categoryIds[] = $category->id;
    }
    return Category::find($categoryIds);
  }
}

class Person extends Eloquent {
  /*
  public function categories() {
    return $this->morphMany('Category','categorizable');
  }
  */
  public function categories(){
    $categoryRows = DB::table('categorizables')
      ->where('categorizable_id', $this->id)
      ->where('categorizable_type', get_class($this))->get();
    $categoryIds = array();
    foreach ($categoryRows as $category) {
      $categoryIds[] = $category->id;
    }
    return Category::find($categoryIds);
  }
}

/*
Table categorizables
id
category_id
categorizable_type (Possible "Article" or "Person" in this case)
categorizable_id (id of Article or Person)

Table categories
id
name

Table articles
id
name
content

Table People
id
name
content
*/
```

Comment: Did you found the solucion? I have a same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198285/many-to-many-polymorphic-relations/17244221#17244221

Comment: No I'm afraid I didn't and after working with L4 for about 1 1/2 month I would say it lacks alot and it makes developing non-trivial stuff harder than using something like CI or Yii...

Comment: i'm create that solution: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9856 is not a better solution, but works