# many-to-many polymorphic relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, polymorphic-associations, eloquent

I need to create a polymorphic relationship between Entity2, Entity1 and Types.
the relationship between event and Types is easy to do, but tou have a problem in the relationship between Entity2 and Types, because it is a many-to-many relation.

[image]

```
class CreateTypesTable extends Migration {
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('types', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('typeable_id');
            $table->string('typeable_type', 20);
            $table->string('name', 20);
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
        });
    }
}

class Entity1 extends Eloquent {
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Type', 'typeable');
    }
}

class Type extends Eloquent {

    public function typeable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

as the relationship between types and Entitys2 is many to many, do not know how to create, because it takes a pivot table.

```
    class Entity2 extends Eloquent {
        public function types()
        {
//          return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Type', 'typeable');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another polymorphic method for a many-to-many relationship: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L805 *morhpToMany* and *belongsToMany* where you pass the related model as a parameter.